# How do I convert nested object to one object

Tags: javascript, object, replace

I would like to convert my below object to a specific format

```
Product: {   "alias":"d8156ad9-06af-45ca-a8eb-17f6148f1bd2",
   "manufacturing_company":{
      "alias":"1",
      "name":"Company",
      "status":1

   },
   "form":{
      "alias":"2",
      "name":"Suppository",
      "status":1

   },
   "generic":{
      "alias":"1",
      "name":"Esomeprazole",
      "status":1
   },
   "name":"AA",
   "trading_price":15,
   "purchase_price":10,
   "pack_size":"10",
   "is_salesable":true,
   "primary_unit":{
      "alias":"1",
      "name":"Form1",
      "status":2
   },
   "secondary_unit":{
      "alias":"1",
      "name":"Form1",
      "status":2
   },
   "conversion_factor":25,
   "code":"201",
   "species":"drfgfgd",
   "strength":"96",
   "full_name":"AA 96",
   "status":1,
   "category":{
      "alias":"8",
      "name":"Test2",
      "status":1
   },
   "subgroup":{
      "alias":"4",
      "name":"CDCD",
      "status":1,
      "product_group":{
         "id":9,
         "alias":"1",
         "name":"zsdfasd",
         "status":1      
      } 
   }
}
```

to

```
Product: {   "alias":"d8156ad9-06af-45ca-a8eb-17f6148f1bd2",
   "manufacturing_company":"1",
   "form":"2",
   "generic":"1",
   "name":"AA",
   "trading_price":15,
   "purchase_price":10,
   "pack_size":"10",
   "is_salesable":true,
   "primary_unit":"1",
   "secondary_unit":"1",
   "conversion_factor":25,
   "code":"201",
   "species":"drfgfgd",
   "strength":"96",
   "full_name":"AA 96",
   "status":1,
   "category":"8",
   "subgroup":"4"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: ^ there ought to be a bot that does this

Comment: `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([k,v])=>typeof v!=='object'?[k,v]:[k,v['alias']]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take for object `alias` or the value for creating a new object.

```js
var data = { alias: "d8156ad9-06af-45ca-a8eb-17f6148f1bd2", manufacturing_company: { alias: "1", name: "Company", status: 1 }, form: { alias: "2", name: "Suppository", status: 1 }, generic: { alias: "1", name: "Esomeprazole", status: 1 }, name: "AA", trading_price: 15, purchase_price: 10, pack_size: "10", is_salesable: true, primary_unit: { alias: "1", name: "Form1", status: 2 }, secondary_unit: { alias: "1", name: "Form1", status: 2 }, conversion_factor: 25, code: "201", species: "drfgfgd", strength: "96", full_name: "AA 96", status: 1, category: { alias: "8", name: "Test2", status: 1 }, subgroup: { alias: "4", name: "CDCD", status: 1, product_group: { id: 9, alias: "1", name: "zsdfasd", status: 1 } } },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(data)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, v && typeof v === 'object'
            ? v.alias
            : v]
        )
    );
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the object and create a new one based on whether the values are scalar or not:

```js
let obj={Product:{alias:"d8156ad9-06af-45ca-a8eb-17f6148f1bd2",manufacturing_company:{alias:"1",name:"Company",status:1},form:{alias:"2",name:"Suppository",status:1},generic:{alias:"1",name:"Esomeprazole",status:1},name:"AA",trading_price:15,purchase_price:10,pack_size:"10",is_salesable:!0,primary_unit:{alias:"1",name:"Form1",status:2},secondary_unit:{alias:"1",name:"Form1",status:2},conversion_factor:25,code:"201",species:"drfgfgd",strength:"96",full_name:"AA 96",status:1,category:{alias:"8",name:"Test2",status:1},subgroup:{alias:"4",name:"CDCD",status:1,product_group:{id:9,alias:"1",name:"zsdfasd",status:1}}}};

let resObj = {}

Object.entries(obj.Product).map(([key, value]) => {
    if(typeof value === "object"){
       resObj[key] = value.alias
    }else{
       resObj[key] = value
    }
})

console.log(resObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

If data is the json you want to convert  , then use the below code to get the desired result.

```
Object.keys(data).reduce((result , current)=>{
    var value = "";
    if(typeof(data[current]) == "object")
    {
        value = data[current]["alias"]
    }
    else{
        value = data[current]
    }
    var d = {}
    d[current] = value;
    Object.assign(result,d);
    return result;
},{})
```